# Spring Batch Not reading from DB nor writing to file

Tags: spring, spring-batch, datasource

I want to use multiple datasources, one for the Spring Batch Metadata and the other for the business data. My batch job just runs and does not even try to connect to the secondaryDataSource. can someone point out what is wrong with my configuration?

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(
            @Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    }
}

public class SpringBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    private static final String QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS = "select * from ...";

    @Bean
    ItemReader<DotDetailsDTO> reader(
            @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource)
            throws SQLException {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<DotDetailsDTO> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

        databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseReader.setSql(QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS);
        databaseReader.setRowMapper(new DOTRowMapper());

        return databaseReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<DotDetailsDTO, DotDetailsDTO> itemProcessor() {
        return new CustomItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<DotDetailsDTO> writer() throws Exception {
        FlatFileItemWriter<DotDetailsDTO> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<DotDetailsDTO>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("file:test.csv"));
        DelimitedLineAggregator<DotDetailsDTO> delLineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<DotDetailsDTO>();
        delLineAgg.setDelimiter(",");
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<DotDetailsDTO> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<DotDetailsDTO>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] { "airwayBillNumber",
                "outboundDate", "orig", "dest", "lotNumber",
                "lotFlightNumber", "lotOrig", "lotDest", "lotPcs", "lotWt",
                "lotFlightDepartDate", "iataCode" });
        delLineAgg.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        writer.setLineAggregator(delLineAgg);
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step1(ItemReader<DotDetailsDTO> reader,
            ItemProcessor<DotDetailsDTO, DotDetailsDTO> processor,
            ItemWriter<DotDetailsDTO> writer) throws SQLException {
        return steps.get("step1").<DotDetailsDTO, DotDetailsDTO> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "firstBatchJob")
    public Job job(@Qualifier("step1") Step step1) {
        return jobs.get("firstBatchJob").start(step1).build();
    }

}

public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="batchDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(
            @Qualifier("batchDataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="secondaryDataSource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource secondaryDataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        ...
        return secondaryDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate secondaryJdbcTemplate(
            @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") final DataSource secondaryDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secondaryDataSource);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Spring Java config
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(DataSourceConfiguration.class);
    context.register(BatchConfiguration.class);
    context.register(SpringBatchConfig.class);
    context.refresh();

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("firstBatchJob");
    System.out.println("Starting the batch job");
    try {
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        System.out.println("Job Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Job completed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Job failed");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow after 2 days I figured out what the issue was. I was not providing new JobParameters because of which I was running the same old broken job over and over.

Below is the fix in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(DataSourceConfiguration.class);
    context.register(BatchConfiguration.class);
    context.register(SpringBatchConfig.class);
    context.refresh();

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("firstBatchJob");
    System.out.println("Starting the batch job");
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        JobParameters jobParam =
            new JobParametersBuilder().addString("jobDate",dateFormat.format(date)).toJobParameters();
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParam);
        System.out.println("Job Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Job completed : " + execution.getJobId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Job failed");
    }

}
```